# Extracting numbers and slashes from a string

Tags: ruby

I have the following string

```
Policy 023203232/02/05 saved successfully
```

And I need to extract `023203232/02/05` from the above string and I have written the following code

```
puts a[/\d+\/\d+\/\d+/]
```

And it works fine. But If the number increases with the slashes like, `023203232/02/05/06` I have to include one more `\d+` but I don't know how many slashes and number would repeat this way, So any one can suggest me to write some generic solution

If string is

```
Policy 023203232/02/05 saved successfully
```

Then

```
023203232/02/05
```

If string is

```
Policy 023203232/02/05/06 saved successfully
```

Then

```
023203232/02/05/06
```

If string is

```
Policy 023203232/02/05/06/08 saved successfully
```

Then

```
023203232/02/05/06/08
```

How to write such a generic regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should be what you're looking for :

```
/(\d+\/?)+/
```

It means :

- At least one pattern of :

  - at least one digit
  - possibly followed by a `/`

It should be a bit more robust than the other answers :

```
"Policy 023203232/02/05/06/08 saved successfully"[/(\d+\/?)+/]
# => "023203232/02/05/06/08"
"Policy 023203232/02/05/07/3434343/56 saved successfully 09/56/32"[/(\d+\/?)+/]
# => "023203232/02/05/07/3434343/56"
"Policy // // 023203232/02/05/07/3434343/56 saved successfully 09/56/32"[/(\d+\/?)+/]
# => "023203232/02/05/07/3434343/56"
```

If you want to make sure that the number is right after 'Policy ' but don't want to have `'Policy '` inside your match, you can use a [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
/(?<=Policy )(\d+\/?)+/
```

Here in action :

```
"2017/03/31 Policy 023203232/02/05/07/3434343/56 saved successfully"[/(?<=Policy )(\d+\/?)+/]
# => "023203232/02/05/07/3434343/56"
```

Comment: This is awesome, this is exactly I am looking for! Accepted your answer!

Comment: My whole message consist of some other number before the word 'Policy' So it's taking those numbers, So I have written the Regular expression this way `puts a[/Policy (\d+\/?)+/]` So it returns the string with policy So I have to delete the word Policy, Do you have any other way to avoid this situation? So Is there any way the word 'Policy' can be avoided from the result of regular expression itself?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming contiguous digits and slashes (i.e. no spaces in between), this should work:

```
a.scan(/\d+\/?/).join
```

Comment: No it's not printing, it's only printing `023203232/`

Comment: @RAJ: sorry - I tested it with `scan`. I've updated my answer with the working version now :-)

Comment: Your code works fine but If I give `str="Policy 023203232/02/05/07/3434343/56 saved successfully 09/56/32` then it's printing `023203232/02/05/07/3434343/5609/56/32`

Answer (score 1):

This one looks for a serie of digits or slashes:

```
str = "Policy 023203232/02/05/07/3434343/56 saved successfully 09/56/3"
p str.match(/[0-9\/]+/)[0] # => "023203232/02/05/07/3434343/56"
```